# Writing, reading, and using specialized data files for C++

Tags: c++

I'm working on a C++ project and part of what I need to do give it the ability to read multiple data files to pull a name, description, and requirements for selecting it which could include having selected a previous data file.  The program is essentially a Pathfinder character creator and the data files or for feats.  I want people to easy add new feats to the list, thus why I want each one to be separate, and I need them to mostly be plain language so that someone can look at one of the files and mostly understand what to do.

Unfortunately none of the C++ resources I have so far cover reading files in this manner nor what languages I could do it in.  What's a good language for me to accomplish this in and how would I grab the data from that file type?  Here's an example feat that can be used to demonstrate:

> Name: Greater Blind-Fight
>
> Prerequisites: Perception 15 (this will be a variable I'd need it to check that it's 15 or higher), Improved Blind-Fight (this is another feat I'd need to make sure was selected)
>
> Benefit: Your melee attacks ignore the miss chance for less than total concealment, and you treat opponents with total concealment as if they had normal concealment (20% miss chance instead of 50%). You may still reroll a miss chance percentile roll as normal.
>
> If you successfully pinpoint an invisible or hidden attacker, that attacker gets no advantages related to hitting you with ranged attacks, regardless of the range. That is, you don’t lose your Dexterity bonus to Armor Class, and the attacker doesn’t get the usual +2 bonus for being invisible.
>
> (may end up being written in a manner that affects other variables)
>
> Special: The Greater Blind-Fight feat is of no use against a character who is the subject of a blink spell.

If it can't be done well in a manner that people can quickly add new files to, that's fine, that bit is just something I'd LIKE to do, not absolutely required, just I'm new to working with C++ and as I said, some reason my resources so far completely skip this sort of thing.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is wrong with let's say, json files?

Comment: Put it simply?  I don't know how to read any file at all with C++.  That's the biggest part of the question.  The other is what would be good to use with this sort of data.  Let me put it this way, I'm trying to make a program that generates a character sheet for people.  Every few levels, including the first, they need to pick from a list of feats.  Choosing these feats sometimes have requirements that need to be taken account that will usually be stored in variables in the program itself.

Comment: Well I think that the question you ask is a bit wrong. You want to know how to model application logic, and then additionally choose right tools. To me it looked like you were asking for tools only. IMO you need to design a model of those feats, to use in application. Regardless of how it is stored in files. Then design and implement tools or methods to serialize and deserialize (storing and loading) them. Also I would discourage you from writing your own tools for this purpose, because there already is a good stuff for it. E.g. JSON format. Use a 3rd party lib.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few human-read/writeable data formats out there, with bindings for every major programming language, some examples with a very basic example how it looks like:

- XML

  ```
  <character>
     <name>foobar</name>
     <abilities>
          <ability>
              <name>perception</name>
              <value>15</value>
          </ability>
      </abilities>
  </character>
  ```
- YAML

  ```
  name: foobar
  abilities:
     - perception: 15
     - ...
  ```

  There is a list of implementations on the official [YAML site](http://www.yaml.org/), which is by the way written in YAML.
- JSON

  ```
  {
      "name": "foobar",
      "abilities": {
          "perception": 15
      }
  }
  ```

Note that the *data format* does not implement your logic. If percpetion >= 15 implies blind-fight you always need to do that yourself.

Comment: Well, it's more I need the feats themselves to be in that sort of format, but I also need to know how to grab that data, especially if I need to have it read all the XML files in a specific folder, though I think I can use something like XML for the feats, so the main question I'd have now then is how do I get it to step through multiple XML files to grab data I put in so it can be listed and selected from the list?  Basically how it's going to work is you select some feats every once in a while, but to select it, you need to meet the prerequisites.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want here. If you need prerequisites / dependencies defined in data files you need to formally define them in a way that your program can interpret them at runtime at make decisions based on them.

Comment: If that's what I need to do, I don't know how to do that.  As I said, I'd prefer being able to have them human readable, but that isn't absolutely necessary, so if I have to define all that, how would I write a datafile for say that example feat and grab that data?

Comment: Start simple. Do everything in the program at first and if that works go for serializing and deserializing the data.

Comment: I'm literally going to need well over 100 of these feats and part of the point of all this is so I can learn what I'm doing.  So yeah, I'd really like a good way to have these in separate files rather then pile them all in somewhere and end up with a cluttered file that I eventually need to transfer out.  If I have to hard code them regardless, fine, but I need at least a good way to keep them sorted out in other files.  When working with this much data, organization is pretty key.  Would it help if I finished up the rest of the program so I can better show what it's eventually going to do?

Comment: No no, I meant that it's probably best to start with the prerequisite logic first and implement loading the files later. I must say, I have a bit the feeling that you are not entirely clear on what your program must do to fulfill its requirements. Maybe think a bit more about it and make a few sketches on paper or a whiteboard or something.

Comment: Pretty clear on what it needs to do, just not the how...  let me post a link here:
http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/character-creation
Basically I'm writing a program that first steps you through these steps and creates their character sheet for them.  On that site, there's a massive list of feats.  I need them to be able to select one or however many they get based on their class/race choice and have them interact with other elements of the character to fill in the sheet.  Some of them require them picking another feat as well, so I need a way to detect that.

Comment: Start simple. Create the stuff without the feats first. Then create the basic feats, using XML or YAML. Once you can read in basic feats, start adding in another step--- like stat prerequisites to pick that feat. Once you have that working, you can then worry about having feats that require other feats before they can be selected. Reading text files is trivial in C++. You can find tutorials on that online. Reading in XML or YAML is well known. You can find parsers for that as well. Start small, progress in baby steps.